# Дополнение содержимого переменной JQ

Tags: jquery

Добрый день,
У меня есть вопрос на тему можно ли переменной A = 1 добавить значение 2 какой-то функцией что бы вышло A = 12? Делаю это в Jquery

Comment: Зачем `jquery` если можно `parseInt(a + "2")` ?

Answer (score 1):

Так:

```
var A = 1;
A = parseInt(A + "2") //12
```